# Scaling UV mapping VS Changing size of Texture

Tags: texturing, uv

If i want to change size of texture i can either

1) scale (S) the UV mapping
2) change the size in texture (x,y,z)

What difference doest it make? I prefer the first option, because then I don't have to change the size once again in outside programs (Unity). But how does it affect performace? Is it a problem when my UV mapping is much larger then 0-1 space?

Thank you very much,

Marty

Comment: Does Unity handles UV maps larger the 0,1? If not (I think it's not but not sure to remember that) probably you'll need to change the texture, meaning repeating it in a new texture.

Comment: It works fine, looks fine. My only concern was not to do something that turns out to be performance expensive. Iam curious: is scale something 10x or change the size to 10 essentially the same thing (in terms of performance)?